# original variable value changes after calculation it's involved in

Tags: javascript

I don't get why this happens;

```
var var1 = 200;
var var2 = var1 += 50;
console.log(var1);
```

When I query var1 I get 250. Shouldn't I get the value of that variable? or is my logic wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/bazzball/pf3eLeoo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code add `50` to `var1`, storing the result in `var1`. then it assign to `var2`, `var1` value.

If you want to add `50` to `var1` and store the result in `var2`, you need to do it with something like:

```
var var1 = 200;
var var2 = var1 + 50;
console.log(var1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is an assignment operator, so what you're actually saying is:

```
var var1 = 200;
var1 += 50; //200 + 50 and assign back to var1
var var2 = var1; //var2 is the value of var1 = 250
```

If you want `var1` to stay at 200 - simply add `50` to it:

```
var var2 = var1 + 50;
```

What `var var2 = var1 += 50;` comes out to:

```
var var2 = var1 = var1 + 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the `+=` operator, this will change the value of your `var1`.

To eliminate this problem, use a singe `+`.

Example:

```
var1=200;
var2=var1+50;
console.log(var1);

//returns 200
```